# Add text block after price for my storeview

Tags: store-view

Help me with this task: I for one can deduce storeview inscription: "VAT, plus Shipping" but for another storeview hide this inscription, i need to display in the catalog and in the product page

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup

This extensions is a must have and has many configuration options. E.g. display tax information or shipping information under price block.
Everything configurable via system->configuration and also store/website individual by selection of store/website scope.